# ActiveAdmin filters by child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have **Order** model which belongs to **User** model.

I need to create filter in orders by user email.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 21):

If you're looking at orders in orders.rb, and want to limit orders by the associated user then you can do:

```
filter :user_first_name, :as => :string
```

which will give you a free text search based on the Order.User.first_name relationship.

The same is true in reverse as long as the has_one and belongs_to relationships are configured correctly:

```
filter :order_created_at, :as => :string
```

Hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for more than:

```
User.where(:email => 'whatever@email.com').orders
```

Comment: I looking like that, but I need to do it as filter in ActiveAdmin